# How to create a .sks file to used in spriteKit app

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I want to create a custom .sks file, and use it in my spriteKit app. but I don't know how to create it.

anyone who can tell me the details about how to create a .sks file.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to create your own sks file?

Comment: Use the Particle Emitter Editor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are particle files.

To create one go to xcode, `File->New->File...`

Then a modal will pop-up go to `Resource-> SpriteKit Particle File`

[image: selecting a particle file]

Then select the particle type:

[image: particle type]

Then you can edit your particle effect with the right side bar:

[image]

For more details about [different particles here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Sprite_Kit_Particle_Emitter_Tutorial)